# Trying to determine and change "Nation/locale/region Code" for application inside disassembler

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida, ollydbg

Inside this program executable (included below), there is something that determines what "nation" the program will start up as. by "nation" i mean the program will either run in Korean, US, Japanese, or Taiwanese version (the version it is in currently). I'm relatively new to using a disassembler (using Ollydbg atm)  and was told a really vague piece of advise that changing the nation is not that hard to do at all.
My question is where would I need to start looking for to change the default nation (or locale, or region) inside this program ? Any help or advise would be appreciated

Program: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oX7b74PUAefn_imU9BubIlVWCT42dBWu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question is more suited to [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). But, even there, you need to at least make an attempt at reverse engineering it.

Comment: My guess is that locale settings come from the OS. Try changing Windows Language settings.